# How to remove on hover property for a submit button with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

On document ready i disabled a form submit button just with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
//disable submit button

$('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

Now depending on a textfield being changed i enable/disable the submit button

```
$("#codetextfield").change(function () {

        if (~$.inArray($(this).val().toLowerCase(), vouchersArr)) {

             $('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $(this).val('Non valid');   
             $('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });//end change
```

But  the button hover effect is still in effect and the user just thinks the form isn't reacting. So how can i remove the button hover effect?

Comment: Why not just add CSS for :disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) rather than remove:

```
$("input[type='submit']").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
```

That will take care of the hover altogether.

P.S.: If you want to set it back, you can do so easily:

```
$("input[type='submit']").on(
    "mouseenter": function(){
        // Do something
    },
    "mouseleave": function(){
        // Do something
    }
});
```

**EDIT** If this still fails for you, you can always enforce CSS on the element, but I suggest you bind a class or an id to your element to make it the focus of the solution. For example let's assume you added a *not-hoverable* class.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/50d0brvh/)

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" class="hoverable" value="Hoverable"></input>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" class="not-hoverable" value="Not Hoverable"></input>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.hoverable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.not-hoverable {
    cursor: arrow;
}
```

This workaround can be applied to the element you want on document ready like so:

```
$(".selector-for-the-submit-button-here").addClass("hoverable");
$(".selector-for-the-other-submit-button-here").addClass("not-hoverable");
```

When dealing with CSS and things like WordPress, you want to make sure that your styles overrule WordPress, if WordPress fights you. As a last resort add `!important` at the end of your CSS statement to ensure your rules are going to work like so:

```
.hoverable {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
.not-hoverable {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Comment: hmm, tried your suggestion but still there is a hover effect. Looking at the html code these classes are added `class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-primary btn-default"`
i also tried $("#input[type['submit']").off('hover');

Comment: @alex that's wordpress for you, I will add a CSS solution for you